# UMD With Ember-CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to load the [gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) in my Ember application via ember-cli. I installed the application via `bower` and imported in my `ember-cli-build.js` file. It includes `_` as a library via:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery', 'lodash'], factory);
}
```

`define.amd` evaulates to `false`

I looked into why this is the case , and found that ember-cli's loader doesn't support `UMD`. On an open cli [issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/issues/47), Stefan Penner, one of the main cli developers, suggested:

> This is by design. As this library requires a pre build step to
>   de-anonymize the modules. That step can do the appropriate munging to
>   work correctly

I have no clue what that means. I got around the issue by manually importing the dependencies of this library in my own `ember-cli-build` before this library but that's defeating the purpose of dependency management. How can I make this library resolve its own modules?

Answer (score 1):

Latest Ember CLI blueprints for new Ember projects contain [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import). `ember-auto-import` is a library that allows to import any NPM library in Ember. No configuration is needed. It could also be installed in projects using an older Ember  CLI version and is the recommended way.

If you don't want to install an additional dependency - even if it's part of official blueprints - Ember CLI not only supports [Standard Named AMD Asset](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-named-amd-asset) via `app.import('path/to/entry-point.js')` but also [Standard Anonymous AMD Asset](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-anonymous-amd-asset):

```
app.import('path/to/entry-point.js', {
  using: [
    { transformation: 'amd', as: 'your-named-import' }
  ]
});
```

As normal this goes into your `ember-cli-build.js`.

Sidenode: For some time [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) was the recommended solution for CommonJS modules. But it has been deprecated in favor of `ember-auto-import`.